# Connection pooling for Snowflake in Java

Tags: java, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, connection, connection-pooling

We are connecting to snowflake from Java application using encrypted private key(this encrypted private key comes from  SNOWSQL_PRIVATE_KEY_PASSPHRASE and private_key which is an API call which will get dynamically)

```
SnowflakeBasicDataSource snowflakeDataSource = new SnowflakeBasicDataSource();
    snowflakeDataSource.setUrl(jdbcAccountURL);
    snowflakeDataSource.setPrivateKey(encryptedPrivateKey);
```

How to do connection pooling using SnowflakeBasicDataSource.I have read some where to use SnowflakeConnectionPoolDataSource.

Our goal is use to reuse the existing connections.if the current connection is invalidated or any issue with the existing connection then only get the new connection for snowflake.

Could you please suggest in this scenario how to do connection pooling using SnowflakeConnectionPoolDataSource and get a new connection if the current connection is not valid.